# C# HttpClient upload percent finishes before actual upload completes

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm working with `.Net 4.7` and I'm uploading some large files to an API via `HttpClient`. The issue that I'm having is that when i use the `ProgressMessageHandler` class handler, the progress reaches 100% before the `client.PostAsync()` call is actually completed. The application is still 'processing' the request even though I don't see network activity any longer. The extra wait time after the 100% completion of the progress handler seems to be proportional to the amount of time the progress took to actually reach 100%

Edit: I don't actually care about the response other than the status code success or fail. I want to know when all of the file is completely uploaded to the endpoint and the request is completed.

```
public static async Task UploadFile(MyClass project)
        {
            using (var handler = new ProgressMessageHandler())
            using (var client2 = HttpClientFactory.Create(handler))
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                string jwtToken = User.JwtToken;
                client2.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                client2.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my-endpoint.com/api/");
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                FileStream fileToUpload = File.OpenRead(project.FilePath);

                var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
                {
                    { new StringContent(project.ProjectMedia), "Name" },
                    { new StreamContent(fileToUpload), "File", project.FilePath }
                };

                handler.HttpSendProgress += (s, e) =>
                {    
                    // This completes 100% in 5 seconds, for example
                    UpdateStatus(e.ProgressPercentage);
                };

                // This will take around another 5 seconds to complete..
                var response = await client2.PostAsync("upload", multipartFormContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Complete");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```cs
var response = await client2.PostAsync("upload", multipartFormContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

1. You're not properly awaiting the `PostAsync()` task - instead you're blocking the thread by calling `.Result`
2. This same line is awaiting `ReadAsStringAsync()`. This is data being downloaded, while you're listening to the `HttpSendProgress` event which tracks the upload. `HttpReceiveProgress` tracks the download.

Ignoring any local parsing of the response, the time it takes `HttpSendProgress` **and** `HttpReceiveProgress` to reach 100% should correspond to the time that `ReadAsStringAsync()` finishes. If you're not downloading much data it might be that `.Result` is your main issue.

---

To fix the above line, you need another `await`:

```cs
var response = await client2.PostAsync("upload", multipartFormContent);
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: So in reality i dont care to even receive the response data, it will be a success message. So a 200 response is all i care about. Ive tried await client2.PostAsync("upload", multipartFormContent); as well as await client2.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false); and i get the same results.

Comment: @user616 Sounds like the API just takes a long time to send a response, even if the response is just a status code. `HttpSendProgress` should reach 100% when the request payload is sent, but if the backend takes a long time to process the request, `PostAsync()` won't finish until the response headers are received.